# Perl command line memory storage

Tags: perl, stack-overflow

I'm trying to pass a command line argument to a program 'notesearch.c' in order to overflow the buffer and rewrite the return address to 0x00007fff9e89b2e7 in little endian format using the command :

> ./notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\xe7\xb2\x89\x9e\xff\x7f\x00\x00" x
> 20')

However, the value stored at argv[1] is :

> 0x7fff9cd441cc:   0xe7  0xb2  0x89  0x9e  0xff  0x7f  0xe7  0xb2
>
> 0x7fff9cd441d4:   0x89  0x9e  0xff  0x7f  0xe7  0xb2  0x89  0x9e
>
> 0x7fff9cd441dc:   0xff  0x7f  0xe7  0xb2  0x89  0x9e  0xff  0x7f ......

The zeros are not stored ! So the actual 64bit overwritten return address can be any permutation of the  non zero hexadecimal digits.
How do i store the zeros as well?

Comment: The arguments go through the shell prior to being processed by `perl`.

Comment: This works: `hexdump -C < <(perl -e 'print "\x00\x00" x 20')`, but this does not work: `hexdump -C <<< "$(perl -e 'print "\x00\x00" x 20')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a unix-like system, it is not possible to pass arguments containing `\0` characters.

Perl is capable of printing the `\0`'s, and some shells may be capable of retaining them in an internal representation of the command line, but when the shell runs the other program, it will do so with the `execve` syscall (all higher-level program execution routines are built on top of `execve`). The format of the `argv` passed to `execve` is NULL-terminated array of `\0`-terminated strings.

This is the kernel ABI for program execution; there's no way around it. You could *almost* reimplement `execve` in userspace with your own ELF parser, but only the kernel can give you the privilege escalation of the set-id bits, and the kernel only does that when you call `execve`.